# kendo.ui.Scheduler ignores both views.showWorkHours and showWorkHours config params

Tags: kendo-ui

I create an scheduler control like the following:

```
<script>
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
        ... ,
        views: [
            {
                type: "day",
                showWorkHours: true
            },
            {
                type: "week",
                showWorkHours: true,
                selected: true
            },
            "month",
            "agenda"
        ],
        showWorkHours: true,
        ...
    });
</script>
```

but all `showWorkHours` params are ignored and full day hours are displayed after the control displayed.

The control correctly understands view types (day, week etc), even that week view is selected by default, but both day and week views ignore business hours and display full day hours.

The Kendo UI doc (http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler#configuration-views.showWorkHours, http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler#configuration-showWorkHours) does not specify any dependencies for the `showWorkHours` params from any other.

Could you please advise where I am wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could be using an old version of the Kendo UI scheduler which doesn't support those options yet. Try upgrading to the latest release.